# fail to locate a button on website using Selenium IDE

Tags: html, css, testing, selenium

JI just started to use Selenium to test a website. However, there a button on the website I cannot locate using both link and xpath.
The URL is http://hra.case.edu/info. If you type like John in the first name input box, the website will render a table that shows the possible user you are. And I need to click the first button "This is me".

Here is my test case source code for Selenium

```
<tr>
    <td>open</td>
    <td>/</td>
    <td></td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>clickAndWait</td>
    <td>link=Get Started</td>
    <td></td>
</tr>

<tr>
    <td>keyPress</td>
    <td>name=searchFirstName</td>
    <td>John</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>selectWindow</td>
    <td>name={&quot;$&quot;:{&quot;memLimit&quot;:2000,<br />&quot;autoFlush&quot;:true,<br />&quot;crossDomain&quot;:false,<br />&quot;includeProtos&quot;:false,<br />&quot;includeFunctions&quot;:false,<br />&quot;currentDomain&quot;:&quot;case.edu&quot;}}</td>
    <td></td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>clickAndWait</td>
    <td>//*[@id='select_user']/tr[1]/td[1]/a</td>
</tr>

It fails at the last step said [error] Element Xpath//*[@id'select_user']/tr[1]/td[1]/a not found
```

Anyone know how to locate that button?
Thanks!
p.s. I can use firebug console to locate that button

```
>>> $x(".//*[@id='select_user']/tr[1]/td[1]/a")
[a.btn /midlife/149]
```

Comment: Okay, problem solved, It is because there is a delay before "this is me button" poped out. Just need to put a waitforelementPresent action before click it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That you just need to wait like that

`command` - `waitForElementPresent`

`target` - `Xpath//*[@id'select_user']/tr[1]/td[1]/a`

Answer (score -1):

Try with below xpath

```
"//div[@id='content']//tbody[@id='select_user']/tr[1]//a"
```

Comment: just to make sure, my code in Selenium is <tr>
 <td>clickAndWait</td>
 <td>//div[@id='content']//tbody[@id='select_user']/tr[1]//a</td>
 <td></td>
</tr>